# .Rprofile: How to set option "browser" correctly (to Chrome) so that help.start() works?

Tags: macos, r

I work on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31). My `~/.Rprofile` is

```
options(repos=c(CRAN="http://cran.ch.r-project.org",
        BioC="http://www.bioconductor.org",
        Omegahat="http://www.omegahat.org/R"),
        pdfviewer=path.expand("~/R/misc/shell_scripts/skim"),
        browser="mybrowser")
```

where `mybrowser` is a file in `/bin/` which contains `open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"`. When I open R and type `help.start()`, all I obtain is that Chrome becomes active, but no real output from `help.start()`. How can I properly set up `browser` in `options` so that `help.start()` works as expected?

I originally just had `browser="Chrome"`, but R couldn't find the browser. I tried several kinds of things to solve this (e.g., `browser="/Applications/Google Chrome.app"` [and various variants to escape the blank]), but none worked. I guess that's because `sh /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app` just does not work. On the Mac, applications are opened via `open -a ...`, that's why I created `mybrowser`. That finally opened the browser, but I couldn't figure out how to get `help.start` to work properly.

Comment: What does `options("help_type")` give you?

Comment: Thanks for helping, Roman. It gives "$help_type" -> "NULL"

Comment: Try `options("help_type" = "html")`.

Comment: Nothing happens; literally, so: options("help_type" = "html") just gives the next prompt ">"

Comment: You have now set html_type. Can you open help in your browser now?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Chrome becomes active (due to my "mybrowser" construction -- otherwise I get again that sh fails), but nothing else happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, Hans-Joerg Bibiko helped out: the solution is to set `browser` to `browser="/usr/bin/open -a 'Google Chrome'"`

Answer (score 3):

Create a **Renviron** file in your home (i.e ~/.Renviron) and add this line.

```
R_BROWSER=google-chrome
```

I'm not sure about "chrome" part, i use conkeror and my setup is :

```
R_BROWSER=conkeror
```

But this should do the tricks

Comment: I used R_BROWSER=chrome. With the option browser=mybrowser nothing changes (Chrome becomes active but nothing more happens). I changed browser to browser=chrome (as it used to be), but then I obtain: sh: chrome: command not found. What is the setting for the option "browser" in .Rprofile?

Comment: @MariusHofert: I think that it's related to your installation/OS of chrome.I don't have a Mac OS (debian instead), so i can't help. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

If you look in `utils:::print.help_files_with_topic` (the function that actually issues the call to `browseURL()`), there is this really annoying line:

```
if (.Platform$GUI == "AQUA" && type == "html") 
    browser <- get("aqua.browser", envir = as.environment("tools:RGUI"))
```

And since `.Platform$GUI == "AQUA"` on OSX, this means that you have to do some trickery to browse help files in your favorite browser.  Hence, in my .Rprofile (located here `path.expand('~/.Rprofile')`, of course), I included these lines.

```
options(help_type='html')
options(browser="/usr/bin/open -a '/applications/Google Chrome.app'")
p  <-  .Platform
p$GUI = 'unknown'
unlockBinding('.Platform', as.environment('package:base'))
assign('.Platform', p , envir=as.environment('package:base'))
lockBinding('.Platform', as.environment('package:base'))
rm(p)
```

So far it doesn't seem to have any effect other than enabling use of an alternate browser, but you may want to read the section labeled "Aqua" in `?.Profile` if you're worried about messing around with `base`.